# Does the phrase "... the both of us" change the meaning of the sentence if it was already plural to begin with?

Tags: phrase-meaning

Someone mentions they've found an old photograph with them and myself depicted on it, and says "We looked so different, the both of us".

Does this mean:

1. We looked different from each other, but now we look more similar.
2. Each of us individually looks different from how we looked like back then.
3. Both of the above, requiring further context.

My gut instinct tells me that just saying "We looked so different" suggest #1, but adding "the both of us" shifts it more in the direction of #2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd assume that the use of the word "both" rather than the more natural "two" would indicate that the speaker means that both of them looked different than they do now, as opposed to meaning that they looked different from *each other*.